# Error loading jquery after migrating to https Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, ssl, https

This problem appeared after migrating from http to https on my website. In admin panel I see this error on every page in console:
"Mixed Content: The page at 'pagename' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://134.249.116.78/jquery.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

I've tried to install several plugins but nothing is working

Comment: Have you tried changing the resource to https as well?